# Tomcat Cors as been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: tomcat, cors

I have set up a Tomcat 7 for an older app on a Windows 2016 server I am getting this error:`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api.timstestite.com' from origin 'timstestite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

I have added this to the web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And I am still getting an error.